# Most efficient way to find elements with same value in 2 collections

Tags: java

Suppose I have a list of hotels,

```
Hotel {
  String name;
  String address;
}
```

and a list of address,

```
Address{
  int id;
  String street;
}
```

Whats the most efficient way to find all hotels in the hotel list whose address equals to street of any address in address list? 
By comparing each hotel with each address, the time complexity is o(n^2) which seems not good.

Thanks.

Comment: are the lists sorted in any way?

Comment: I don't think there is another way then to go through all the Hotel objects and to take the address of this hotel and to check if it is available in the Address list. Of course you could stop your loop once the address is found, so in practice it will be less then o(n^2)

Comment: Iterate the hotel list in `O(n)`, construct a `Map` of names (by address) to a `List` of `Hotel` (a `HashMap<String, Hotel>`) which should take `O(1)` to construct in that iteration. Finally, look up the address of interest in the `Map` (an `O(1)` operation).

Comment: you can create HashMap, and put street as a key, and class collecting hotel and adress as a value (or lists). And then check the hashmap for values with hotel and adress not null

Comment: just use hashing

Comment: What is the format of `Hotel.address`? Is it just a street name or is it "123, Acacia Avenue, Sunny Town, P05T C0D3, Elbonia"?

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful answers, I'm now using a `HashMap<String,Hotel>` as @ElliottFrisch suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to store the addresses in a set.

```
Set<String> streets = addressList.stream()
    .map(address -> address.street)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
Collection<Hotel> filtered = hotels.stream()
    .filter(hotel -> streets.contains(hotel.address))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I assume hotel.address is something like "123, Acacia Avenue, Sunny Town" and therefore won't be contained in any set of streets.

Comment: It sounds to me that the user is working through an exercise. He was speaking about time complexity of iterating over both lists. If the address was not a street and there was another more concrete way of comparing them, then he would have provided it in his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<Address> groupByResult = 
     addressList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Address::getStreet)
```

And then just use the collection of Addresses to do the lookup, which will be fast.